# How do I start Ubuntu from grub?

Tags: grub2

Today, after installing some updates, (I have no idea what updates),  Ubuntu asked to be restarted, but when I restarted, it restarted into grub. How do I start Ubuntu from grub?

Edit: the specific text I see is:
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>_

Comment: It would depend on the specific Grub screen you are looking at.  If you would write down the text that is on the screen and place it into your question that would help.  Just starting from Grub would only be a part of the resolution.  The best thing would be to start out with the specific reason it's stopping at Grub.

Comment: Take a Pic of the Screen with your Cell and Upload that!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't take a picture where the text is readable, but I have updated my question.